# HTML: keeping checkbox checked after page refresh

Tags: php, html

I would like to keep the checked boxes to stay checked when the page is refreshed.

Actually my page is not just refreshed, I mean like I have pagination and if I hit the next button the url will change like `index.php?page=2`

The below code can keep the boxes checked after refreshing page but fails when I click on the next page and the url changes to as the above.

So how do i keep the boxes checked? I have tried putting `$_GET['page']` on the checkbox but it doesn't work.

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="s" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['s'], $_GET['page'])?' checked':'')?>/> Small<br>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function(){
     $('.checkbox').on('change',function(){
        $('#form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the `php` part which creates the page id. I have this `php` code below the above form:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }
        else
        {
            $page = 1;
        }


        /*
         * Set a few of the basic options for the class, replacing the URL with your own of course
         */
        $options = array(
            'results_per_page'              => 2,
            'url'                           => 'index.php?page=*VAR*',
            'db_handle'                     => $dbh
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

For modern browsers you can use `localStorage` like so

```
$(function(){
    var value = localStorage.input === 'true' ? true: false; // 1
    $('input').prop('checked', value || false);
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CC2hC/1**

When the input is changed you store the value in localStorage, and when the page loads again you check if it is there and apply the value or default to `false`

For older browsers you will probably have to use cookies or a database.

You have to check the value on the line with the comment `// 1` because prop accepts a boolean value whereas the localStorage value would be a `string`